# drop a single tuple from a multi tuple column

Tags: pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
<bound method DataFrame.info of <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
MultiIndex: 369416 entries, (datetime.datetime(2008, 1, 2, 16, 0), 'ABC') to     (datetime.datetime(2010, 12, 31, 16, 0), 'XYZ')
Data columns:
b_val    369416  non-null values
dtypes: float64(1)>
```

From this, I want a dataframe that has dates as the indexes and 'ABC' to 'XYZ' as column names with the values as the values under the column 'b_val'. I tried to do:

```
new_data = new_data.unstack()
```

But this gives me:

```
<bound method DataFrame.info of <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Index: 757 entries, 2008-01-02 16:00:00 to 2010-12-31 16:00:00
Columns: 488 entries, ('b_val', 'ABC') to ('b_val', 'XYZ')
dtypes: float64(488)>
```

Is there a way to transform this another way or is there a way to drop 'b_val' from each of the column names?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) is the correct way to do what you've done.

You could drop the first level from the the column names (a MultiIndex) using `droplevel`:

```
df.columns = df.columns.droplevel(0)
```

Here's an example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 'a', 22], [1, 'b', 27], [2, 'a', 35], [2, 'b', 56]], columns=['date', 'name', 'value']).set_index(['date','name'])
df1 = df.unstack()

In [3]: df1
Out[3]:
      value
name      a   b
date
1        22  27
2        35  56

In [4]: df1.columns = df1.columns.droplevel(0)

In [5]: df1
Out[5]:
name   a   b
date
1     22  27
2     35  56
```

However, a cleaner option is just to [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html) the *column* (the series):

```
In [6]: df.value.unstack()
Out[6]:
name   a   b
date
1     22  27
2     35  56
```

Comment: Thanks, Andy! I tried the droplevel(0) at one point, but I was assigning the result to df instead of df.columns and ended up with just col names as the dataframe. Didn't see what was going on :-/

Comment: @pynewbie Now I think about it, unstacking the *series* is a "cleaner" way to do this. I've kept in the droplevel (as this answers the question in the title) :)